# Gson nested class parameters have no values

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have issue with parsing string to nested classes. This is my json string:

```
[
 {
  "DeviceName":"devtest",
  "StolenFlag":false,
  "BatteryLevel":2,
  "LastLocalization":{
     "Geography":{
        "CoordinateSystemId":4326,
        "WellKnownText":"POINT (52.403371 16.955098)"
         }
      }
 },
 {
  "DeviceName":"testdev2",
  "StolenFlag":false,
  "BatteryLevel":2,
  "LastLocalization":{
     "Geography":{
        "CoordinateSystemId":4326,
        "WellKnownText":"POINT (16.955098 52.403371)"
         }
      }
 }
]
```

My classes:

```
class Geography implements Parcelable{
    @SerializedName("CoordinateSystemId")
public int CoordinateSystemId;

@SerializedName("WellKnownText")
public String WellKnownText;
....
}

class MyDevice implements Parcelable{
    @SerializedName("DeviceName")
    public String DeviceName;

    @SerializedName("StolenFlag")
    public Boolean StolenFlag;

    @SerializedName("BatteryLevel")
    public int BatteryLevel;


    @SerializedName("LastLocalization")
    public Geography LastLocalization;

    ...
}
```

And converting code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<MyDevice> MyDev = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<MyDevice>>() {
            }.getType());
```

Since Device's parameters are converted correctly I get null/0 values in Geography object inside Device. Do you have any ideas why?

I receive a list with Devices and each contains Geography object. That object's parameters are null/0. I hope you understand.

@EDIT@

I have changed 
`public Geography LastLocalization;`
to 
`public Map<String, Geography> LastLocalization;`

And it works fine, but got an error in writeToParcel method. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(DeviceName);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (StolenFlag ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeInt(BatteryLevel);
        dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an extra level that you haven't accounted for: `LastLocalization` is not a `Geography` object, it is an object that has a `Geography` field that is a `Geography` object.

Comment: I understand, but how is it even possible while in my server Device class has just one Geography object? Thats werid.

Comment: Change `public Geography LastLocalization;` to `public Map<String, Geography> LastLocalization;`

Comment: Works pretty nice now - I get values. But now I get an error with `dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization, 0);` in Device's writeToParcel method. No idea how to fix that, becouse I need to implement this interface.

Comment: Try `dest.writeParcelable(LastLocalization.get("Geography"), 0);`

Comment: It's not giving any errors but my app crashes when I try to put List as extra to Intent. Before chages it was working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@SerializedName("LastLocalization")
public Geography LastLocalization;
```

This definition tells Gson that you're expecting a Geography type object named LastLocalization, and you want to store that in a member called LastLocalization.

Your input has an array of objects, each of which contains an object named LastLocalization, which then contains an object called Geography.

When Gson encounters the LastLocalization object in the JSON, it also sees *by explicity annotation* that it should match your LastLocalization member, so it creates a new Geography object and assigns it there.  It creates a Geography object because that's the type of the member - *nothing else makes sense there*.  However, none of the JSON LastLocalization object properties match any of the java Geography object properties, so Geography just contains the default values for a Java object.

Please realize that Gson doesn't care if the name of a JSON object is different than your Java object because your Java object was explicitly annotated to receive something with a different JSON name.